Python requests Selenium issue with ChromeDriver headless mode only
I want to scrape a facebook ads website using requests library and Selenium with ChromeDriver (because I need to run it on pythonanywhere which has chromedriver).
so I do:

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()

arguments = [
    "--disable-notifications",
    "--start-maximized",
    "disable-infobars",
    "--disable-gpu",
    "--headless",
    "window-size=1980,1080",
    "--allow-running-insecure-content",
    "--disable-extensions",
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
    "--test-type",
    "--disable-web-security",
    "--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection"
]

for argument in arguments:
    chrome_options.add_argument(argument)

prefs = {
    "intl.accept_languages": "en-US"
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36")

# Path to your ChromeDriver
chrome_driver_path = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"  # This is typically the path on PythonAnywhere

# Set up the WebDriver
service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

Setup driver and then scrape the page:
def scrape_page(companyId, companyName):
    # Navigate to the Facebook Ads Library page
    url = f'https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=NL&view_all_page_id={companyId}&search_type=page&media_type=all'
    driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5) 
print(driver.page_source)

Of coursem sleep is not good for long term usage. I should use WebDriverWait. but for now I want to make it work.
But what it prints is the HTML with script tags. Looks like page was not loaded properly. When I remove headless I see browser running and loading page properly and script prints everything loaded.
Any ideas how to this this?

Try --headless=new or --headless=chrome. What version of selenium are you using?

I see stacktraces then, I use newest selenium

you should use WebDriverWait until an element is present. (docs)
you cant be sure of what the driver does in headless mode so you need to make sure using waitUntil rather than a simple sleep.
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element"))
    )


but even sleep for 1 minute does not load it, in headless mode it does not renders the page at all, thats the case
